# SQL Server CE update or insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

In my Windows Forms application, I'm using a SQL Server Compact database. I have a function in which I want to update the columns 'id' and 'name' in table 'owner', unless the specified id does not exist, in which case I want new values inserted.

For example, my current table has 'id' 1 and 2. It MIGHT have 'id' 3. User enters data to insert/update id 3.

I want my query to do something like this:

```
UPDATE owner 
SET name = @InputN 
WHERE id = 3

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
   INSERT INTO owner (id, name) VALUES 3, @InputN
```

How should I define my query in order to make this work in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Comment: SQL CE does not have any procedural extensions like `IF`; it only supports DDL and DML like from the 1970s. You will have to perform the test in your Forms app and call `UPDATE` or `INSERT` from that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in your form codes. This way you don't even need to check if there is an di with the value=3. It will check it by itself and update the row if it exists. If not you won't get any errors.

```
RSSql.UpdateNonQueryParametric("update owner set name=? where id=3", newname);


public static void UpdateNonQueryParametric(string query, params Object[] parameters)
        {
            SqlCeParameter[] param = new SqlCeParameter[parameters.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                param[i] = new SqlCeParameter();
                param[i].Value = parameters[i];
            }
            _cnt = new SqlCeConnection();
            _cnt.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;

            _cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
            _cmd.Connection = _cnt;
            _cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            _cmd.CommandText = query;
            _cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            if (_cnt.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                _cnt.Open();

            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _cmd.Dispose();

            if (_cnt.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                _cnt.Close();
            _cnt.Dispose();
        }
```